# New refresh_token should not get created when the grant_type is refresh_token while using node-oauth2-server npm package

Tags: node.js, postgresql, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement an Oauth2 Framework for my node Application using Postgres Database.I came across a node npm package named [node-oauth2-server](https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server) which gives inbuilt out of the box `OAuth2 framework`.

I also read this [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2) from `IETF` which describes about the `OAuth2 framework` in detailed manner. According to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2) documentation, whenever the `access_token` is invalid we can regenerate a new `access_token` with the `refresh_token` being passed to the `authorization` server. The document states the new `access_token` need not have a new `refresh_token`.

My requirement is that whenever I use the `grant_type` as `refresh_token`, I need to generate only a new `access_token`. While going [this](https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server) npm package, I could see that it is generating a new `refresh_token` whenever the grant_type is `refresh_token`.

Can somebody help me how to ensure that only the `access_token` is generated when the `grant_type` is `refresh_token` using the [node-oauth2-server](https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server) npm package?

The code which regenerates the `refresh_token` in the npm package is as follows

```
 function generateRefreshToken (done) {
      if (this.config.grants.indexOf('refresh_token') === -1) return done();

      var self = this;
      token(this, 'refreshToken', function (err, token) {
      self.refreshToken = token;
      done(err);
  });
}
```

I have also gone through these links on github and stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer

1. [node-oauth2-server example on Postgres](https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server/tree/master/examples/postgresql)
2. [Oauth2 refresh token regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845529/oauth2-refresh-token-regenerating)
3. [Refresh tokens in oauth2 should not be replaced when getting a new access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725304/refresh-tokens-in-oauth2-should-not-be-replaced-when-getting-a-new-access-token)

Comment: could you please check expires value of refresh_token in DB as may be it is already expired so the lib is generating it again.

Comment: I checked the expire value of the refresh_token in the db and it has not yet expired. Still it is generating every single time when the grant-type is refresh_token

Comment: there is other point, the refresh token expire should not be less than the access token expire, otherwise will be useless, there is 2 assumption I have, 1st that lib will compare expire date of refresh and access token against each other, or 2nd generate refresh token each time create new access token, to not have the case that refresh token to expire before access token, check if the refresh token expire is null, it should represent immortal refresh token.

Comment: According the Documentation, the default accessTokenLifetime is 3600 and  refreshTokenLifetime is 1209600. So 1st condition is out. Secondly, I can pass a parameter called refreshTokenLifetime as null to give me immortal refreshToken but still it creates a new refresh_Token on the grant type as refresh_token.

Comment: so may be it is a bug did you mentioned this issue on GitHub?

Comment: Didn't Post a bug!!!! will do it today!!!